# Make a jquery tooltip dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can make a dynamic jQuery tooltip with `.mousemove`, as that when mouse enter on words `Tooltip1` Or `Tooltip2` Or `Tooltip3` show contents same tooltip.

Here is a sample of my html: http://jsfiddle.net/JGx52/4/

```
<ul>
    <li class="style">
    <div class="tooltip" style="bottom: 406px; left: 565px; opacity: 0.9; display: none; ">
         Simple or Rich A simple call such as $("img[title]").tooltip(); will enable tooltips by taking advantage of the element's title attribute. If you want complex tooltips with images, tables, forms and links that's possible by placing the tooltip element manually next to the trigger element. Configure design, timing and positioning Use CSS to create rounded borders, arrows, gradients or shadows. Big or small, high or low. Use the configuration to tweak pre and post-delays and positioning to your personal needs. Fading, sliding, dynamic Tooltip comes with two built-in effects: toggle, and fade and one separate effect, slide, and you can easily build your own effects. The dynamic plugin will dynamically change the tooltip's position so that it always stays in the viewport. File size: 1.10 Kb This tool has all the features and configuration options you'll possibly need, such as effect and a plugin framework, scripting API and an event model. A smaller codebase is easier to control and results in snappier behaviour. Without gzipping the size is 3.5 Kb.
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="">ToolTip1</a></li>
    <li class="style">
    <div class="tooltip">
         jQuery Lint (edge)
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="">ToolTip2</a></li>
    <li class="style">
    <div class="tooltip">
         Please read the documentation. For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="">ToolTip3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you want to....show Tooltip1's contents when you hover over ToolTip1, etc.?

Comment: that's right. how is it? (i not want use from plugin)

Comment: sorry, you want to show the content inside the <a> element or the title attributes content?

Comment: i not want a new tag or use title, i want show `display: block` class `.tooltip` in html code.

Comment: sorry, i'm just still confused. all you want is for anything with class of tooltip to show display:block on hover?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QGTTN/9/ but in my code and css.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you want this presented, but with the provided CSS and markup, [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/WHgRm/):

```
$('a.tool_tip').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev('.tooltip').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).prev('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Comment: I want this but it not worked true in my css and html: http://jsfiddle.net/JGx52/5/

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/QGTTN/10/

Comment: i have no clue what that means. but here is your code http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/JGx52/6/

Comment: last try. sorry, its really difficult to understand you, as well as you didn't say not to alter your css.  here, just added the script http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/JGx52/7/

Comment: ok, not difference between http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/JGx52/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/JGx52/5/ in Result !!!!!!!!!?

Comment: You to understand me, the next comment. you tell me why not work true my tooltip in here: http://jsfiddle.net/JGx52/5/